# how to delete nested array object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc

[how to Delete red Mark item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E11j1.png)

I add my JavaScript code
...i don't generate nested array object deleted function any one can help me

how to delete nestobj:

"value": "10"

"value": "20"

"value": "20"

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var tr;
    var obj = [{ obj1: { "name": "v1", nestobj: [{ "value": "10" }, { "value": "20" }, { "value": "20" }] } }];

    obj.push({ obj1: { "name": "v2", nestobj: [{ "value": "abc" }, {"value": "xyz"}] } });


    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].obj1.name + "</td>")
        $('tbody').append(tr);


        for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length; j++)
        {                
            tr.append("<p>" + obj[i].obj1.nestobj[j].value + " <input type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='&quot;);'> </p>")
            $('tbody').append(tr);

        }       
        tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length + " <input type='submit' value='Remove All' onclick='&quot;);'> </td>")
        $('tbody').append(tr);

    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you paste that code here as text so we can edit it a little more easily?

Comment: please kindly click in [Javascript Code] tag @gyre

Comment: yap i added  my code please check out it @gyre

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like following:

```
$(function () {
var tr;
var obj = [{ obj1: { "name": "v1", nestobj: [{ "value": "10" }, { "value": "20" }, { "value": "20" }] } }];

obj.push({ obj1: { "name": "v2", nestobj: [{ "value": "abc" }, {"value": "xyz"}] } });


for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].obj1.name + "</td>")
    $('tbody').append(tr);


    for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length; j++)
    {                
        var $delBtn = $("<input>",{type:"submit",value:"Delete"});
        var $p = $("<p>",{text:obj[i].obj1.nestobj[j].value});
        $delBtn.on("click",function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        $p.append($delBtn);
        tr.append($p);
        $('tbody').append(tr);

    }     
    var $removeAll = $("<input>",{type:"submit",value:"Remove All"});
    var $col = $("<td>",{text: obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length});  
    $removeAll.on("click",function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("p").remove();
    });
    $col.append($removeAll);
    tr.append($col);
    $('tbody').append(tr);

}
```

});

It is all about adding events to your inputs to remove the items

```js
$(function () {
    var tr;
    var obj = [{ obj1: { "name": "v1", nestobj: [{ "value": "10" }, { "value": "20" }, { "value": "20" }] } }];

    obj.push({ obj1: { "name": "v2", nestobj: [{ "value": "abc" }, {"value": "xyz"}] } });


    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].obj1.name + "</td>")
        $('tbody').append(tr);


        for (var j = 0; j < obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length; j++)
        {                
            var $delBtn = $("<input>",{type:"submit",value:"Delete"});
            var $p = $("<p>",{text:obj[i].obj1.nestobj[j].value});
            $delBtn.on("click",function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            $p.append($delBtn);
            tr.append($p);
            $('tbody').append(tr);

        }     
        var $removeAll = $("<input>",{type:"submit",value:"Remove All"});
        var $col = $("<td>",{text: obj[i].obj1.nestobj.length});  
        $removeAll.on("click",function(){
            $(this).closest("tr").find("p").remove();
        });
        $col.append($removeAll);
        tr.append($col);
        $('tbody').append(tr);

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```